# How to get the Sitecore.Current.Site object inside custom save action WFFM?

Tags: c#, sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I'm using **Sitecore Webforms For Marketers**. In the `save action` of my form I get the `Sitecore.Context.Site` object, but the object doesn't return the right context. The value is "modules_shell".
Does anyone know how I can get the right context?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing the specifics of your setup I would suggest determining the correct site in the same way that Sitecore's site resolver does:

```
var url = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url; 
var siteContext = Sitecore.Sites.SiteContextFactory.GetSiteContext(url.Host, url.PathAndQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have code for this exact problem here: http://firebreaksice.com/sitecore-context-site-resolution/