# How to get the site context from a form using WFFM?

Tags: c#, forms, web-services, sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I'm using Sitecore Webforms For Marketers in a multi-language environment (e.g. .com, .be, .nl en .de). There are 3 servers: 2 Content Delivery Servers (CDS) en 1 Content Management Server (CMS). On the CDS servers is no possibility to write data, so i have configured a webservice to forward the form data from the CDS to the CMS server.

My problem is that the Web service communicates with the .com domain. By using the .com domein for webservice communication, the CMS doesn't have any know how what the site context is from the submitting domain. For example, a user submits a form on the .nl domain, the CMS server thinks it's coming form the .com domain.

Does anyone know how i can get the site context (e.g. NL-nl) from the submit?

Thanks a lot!

Jordy

Comment: @MarkUrsino this is what I thought at first. But this is about web service call which uses single domain host instead of being differentiated depending on current host. That's why Jordy cannot retrieve site in a way described in linked question. Definitely not a duplicate of linked question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created for each domain a custom save action. This solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20800966/how-to-get-the-sitecore-current-site-object-inside-custom-save-action-wffm) and answered by [@TwentyGotoTen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2124993/twentygototen). The place where you need to get the current site is different than in linked question, but the answer is the same. Use the code which is used by Sitecore to resolve site:

```
var url = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url; 
var siteContext = Sitecore.Sites.SiteContextFactory.GetSiteContext(url.Host, url.PathAndQuery);
```

The extended version of the code for resolving sites (linked in the same question by [@MarkUrsino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134360/mark-ursino)) can be found in article [Sitecore Context Site Resolution](http://firebreaksice.com/sitecore-context-site-resolution/).

Can you use the proper domain for each web service call? If you have to call web service using `.com` domain only, maybe you can try to check `UrlReferrer` instead of current request `Url` host?

Comment: I notice it was @Jordy that asked that question too :)

Comment: Hah haven't checked the author of the question ;] Well spotted. @Jordy did you included code from the linked question to your application? Does it work in the new scenario? Do you need to call the web service using `.com` domain? Can you pass the site name as additional form value?

Comment: That works OK when the configured webservice is refering to the same domain as the submit is coming from. As the submit is coming from the .be domain and in the configfile the webservice is refering to the .com domain, the site context is not correct.

Comment: Can you resolve the site using `UrlReferrer.Host` instead of `Url.Host`?

Comment: No. The UrlReferrer.Host is null. I can get Url.Host, but that's the url configured in the configuration file for communicating with the webservice.

Comment: Can you place a hidden input on the form with the site name?

Comment: I have created a custom save action. Can i get the site context by formid? Note: the forms are located in the system item.

Comment: Hidden fields? Yes, but that's not recommended for security reasons.

Comment: Is each of the forms used in one place only (or in the context of one site)? If yes, then using the form id, you can find the form and then get all the items which refer this form ( http://sdn.sitecore.net/Snippets/Item%20Handling/Checking%20References/get%20all%20Items%20that%20refer%20to%20a%20particular%20Item.aspx ).

Comment: If you have configured a web service, why not just resolve reference to the site on CD and pass that in as an additional parameter of your web service call? Maybe get the ID of the home node, you can then resolve that on your CM server.

Answer (score 0):

Update your web service to pass an extra parameter for the host name (via the CD clients) and then on the service (on your CM) get the context site from that.

Comment: I don't think the issue is the hostname, it's resolving that to a site context in CM, which will have different URLs for the editing interface. As I commented Maras' answer, I think he should resolve the site on CD and pass the ID of the home node for the context site. He can then re-resolve on CM, but it really depends exactly what needs to be achieved. I'm not sure if `GetSiteContext()` works if you have multiple domains defined in `<site hostName="" />` if so the CD domains could be defined there for CM too.